# Get the IIS plugins list (such as WebDav)

Tags: c#, iis

How can I obtain the IIS plugins list (such as WebDav) inside my C# application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully define what is the IIS "plugins" you care as there are three types,

1. IIS modules, which you can read from `applicationHost.config`.
2. IIS Manager modules, which you can read from `administration.config`.
3. IIS components/features that associated with CBS. That controls which IIS features or role serivices are enabled. For that you need to check Windows CBS documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  The configuration file is called applicationhost.config It's stored here:

My Documents > IIS Express > config

usually (not always) one of these paths will work

**%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config**
**%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config**